# Categories without identities

Tags: category-theory, terminology, universal-algebra

What's the name of "categories without identities", i.e. of digraphs with just an associative binary operation on its "matching" arrows (disregarding identities)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Semicategory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semicategory). ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks, now I have something to google for. (Or can *you* tell: Is there an interesting theory of semicategories?)

Answer (score 1):

[Semigroupoid.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroupoid)  ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: This terminology fits to "category = monoidoid".

Comment: @martin-brandenburg I am not a fan of this terminology, but I think the idea was that semigroupoids generalize semigroups just like groupoids generalize groups.